# Excel Vlookup , too few arguments error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

When I try to enter Vlookup formula manually in Excel, I get the following error;
[excel manual vlookup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOAvc.jpg). This error appears while I'm defining the second element of the formula from another excel file and it doesn't let me to define the area.And it directs me to use formula wizard, however it's not useful and efficient for me. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

You may find the formula I try to use as below;

```
=vlookup(S2;'[Copy of Material Master_S112.xlsx]q_S112'!$G$2:$I$7
```

after this point it doesn'let me to make any change and directs me to formula wizard.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to show what formula you have tried.

Comment: Why don't you have a closing `)` ?

Comment: It's because the formula does not let me to finish properly.

Comment: Why are you using semicolons to separate arguments instead of commas? Should be something like `=VLOOKUP(S2, '[Copy of Material Master_S112.xlsx]q_S112'!$G$2:$I$7, 2, FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

[`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) takes 4 arguments:

1. Value to seek.
2. Target range.
3. Number of result column relative to the first column of target range. E.g. if your target range is `$G:$I` and you need results from column `H` this parameter should be `2`, if you want results from column `I` - then `3`.
4. Parameter specifying whether you need exact (`TRUE`) or approximate (`FALSE`) match. Set it to `FALSE` in most cases.

And of course you need closing parenthesis `)` at the end.

So the correct formula should look something like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(S2;'[Copy of Material Master_S112.xlsx]q_S112'!$G$2:$I$7;3;FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, the actual problem is I get an error while I'm defining my target range. So I can not enter the rest of the formula. I shared the part that I could enter in the formula. When I use formula wizard I can apply the formula for target range and do not get any error but it's not efficient.

Comment: The error message says you finished typing the formula too early (either by pressing Enter or exiting the cell). You need to type the rest of the arguments separated by `;`

Comment: I do not click enter or exit from any cell. When I enter the target area at first it doesn't give error but when I make shift+control+down arrow it gives the error. Normally that was always working but for a several days I have this issue.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe list separators have changed in your system (`,` instead of `;`)?

Comment: May I ask where may I check it ?

Comment: Control Panel / Region and Language / Formats tab / Additional Settings / Numbers tab / List separator

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ctrl-Shift-Down after you have started to enter the second parameter you will get the "you have entered too few arguments" message.

You can only use Ctrl-Shift-Down after selecting a cell but before you have entered anything for the second VLOOKUP parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, arguments in Excel formulas are separated by commas, not semicolons.

For example,

```
=VLOOKUP(S2, '[Copy of Material Master_S112.xlsx]q_S112'!$G$2:$I$7, 2, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers. It's kind of interesting but, I have to hit at first shift and then control not to get this error. It wasn't like that before but when I hit control first and then shift+down it gives the error. But at least it works like this.

Comment: Can you describe what state is Excel in just before you get the error? What is in the formula bar? Are you editing formula inside the cell or in formula bar? What worksheet and book you are on? Where is the cell cursor and what cells are selected?

Answer (score 0):

if you use win 10  , you must change the regoin configoration .
in control panel > region >formats> additional setting> list separator 
change content to ";"